# Scroll a randomply placed game objects in puzzle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and c# scripting,
I need your help,
I'm creating a jigsaw puzzle game for mobile, I divided the screen in half, the upper part is where the pieces should be placed (rightplace) and the lower part should be a scrolling area for a randomly placed pieces of this puzzle. so every time I start the game, I should have a scrolling area with different pieces of this puzzle.

I used this script to place the pieces randomly in a rectangle, but i don't know how to make them placed in a scrolling panel.

```
void Start()
    {
        //make pieces's positions random
        RightPosition = transform.position;
        transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0.20f, 5.1f), Random.Range(-3.90f, -7.50f));
        
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use a [Scroll Rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ScrollRect.html) and make the pieces children of that scroll rect with random child indices using [SetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html)